# how to pass span value into laravel controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms

I am developing some ticket selling program, where I made an auto calculating ticket price. I put the total price into a `<span>` tag. I'm trying to put it on `<input>` tag so it will be easier to pass the value into controller, but it doesn't work. I've already searching for the solution but it never comes to end. This is what my blade looks like:

```
                  <table class="text-center  table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Quantity</th>
                              <th>Total</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr class="quantz">
                            <td class="product-quantity">
                                <input type="hidden" name="price[]" class="price" id="price" size="5px" readonly value="25000">
                                <input type="number" onchange="update();return false;" name="qty" value="1" min="1" id="quant" class="fl qty-text" >
                            </td>
                            <td class="product-total">
                                <span id="demo">IDR 25.000,-</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><h3><small>Your Cart Total - </small></h3></td>
                          <td><h3><input type="hidden" name="totalz" value=""><span id="sub_total">IDR 25.000,-</span></h3></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
```

and this is what i wrote in my jquery to get the value:

```
<script>
    function update() {
    var total = 0;
    var fees = 0;
    var total_fees = 0;
    var tax_fix = 0;
    var with_fee = 0;
    var discount_amt = 0;
    var no_fee= 0;
    var tax= 0;
    $("#form-ui tr.quantz").each(function(i,o){
    if($(o).find("#quant").val()>=0){
      total += $(o).find("#quant").val() * $(o).find(".price").val();
      $(o).find("#demo").html(rupiah($(o).find("#quant").val() * $(o).find(".price").val()));
    }
    });
    console.log()
    fees  = (total*1);
    total_fees  = total+fees ;
    no_fee  = total;
    with_fee  = total + total_fees;

    //sub total
     $("#st").val(total);
     $("#sub_total").html(rupiah(total));

    //convinence_fee

    if(total == 0){
      fees = 0;
      total_fees = 0;
    }
      $("#fee").val(fees);
      $("#conv").html(rupiah(fees));
      //total_paid
      $("#total_price").val(total_fees);
      $("#total_paid").html(rupiah(total_fees));
      $("#hide_price").val(total_fees);

    }
    $("#form_payment tr.quantity").change(update);

    function rupiah(value){
    value += '';
    x = value.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }
    return 'IDR ' + x1 + x2 + ",-";
    };
  </script>
```

is there any solution regarding this problem? should I put something in my script or my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible with JQuery, jQuery supports chaining objects return.

**In HTML** :

```
<span id="demo">IDR 25.000,-</span>
<input id="totalz" type="hidden" name="totalz" value="">
```

**In JS** :

```
var data = $('#demo').html();
$('#total').val(data);
```

Make sure that, you have single id `demo`, `total`, if you have multiple id with same attribute, then it will conflict with JavaScript

Comment: it works, but because of the value of the <input> is empty, it still return null in controller. how to put it in the value?

Comment: @Farah, do you add the `id="totalz"` ?

Comment: Seems like you have multiple input with name `totalz`, In this case you neeed to pass $id for make all field different

Comment: ah, I see. I put $('#total').html(data); not $('#total').val(data); now it works. thank you very much!