# How to pass span value to controller laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am making a product cart where there are sub total and grand total. Both of them are in A `<span>` tag. I want to pass the grand total value into controller, but somehow it doesn't work and always return null for grandtotal.
Here's the code.

```
 function priceTotal() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $('#cart_checkout > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            var qty = $(this).find('.qty-input').val()
            var price = parseInt($(this).find('.price').text());
            var subTotal = qty * price;
            grandTotal += subTotal;
            $(this).find('.subtotal').text('Rp. ' + subTotal.toLocaleString('en'));
        });
        $('.grandtotal').text('Rp. ' + grandTotal.toLocaleString('en'));

        var data = $('#grandtotal').html();
        $('#grandtotal').val(data);

    }

$(document).ready(function() {
        priceTotal();
        $('.increment-btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var incre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
            var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
            value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
            if (value < 100) {
                value++;
                $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
            }

            priceTotal();
        });


        $('.decrement-btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
            var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
            value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
            if (value > 1) {
                value--;
                $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
            }

            priceTotal();
        });
    });
```

```
                <div class="card ">
                    <table class="table" id="cart_checkout">
                        <thead class="bg-transparent">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Thumbnail</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Brand</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Product</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Size</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Price</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach($cartlists as $cartlist)
                        <tbody class="bg-transparent" class="checkout_cart">
                            <tr class="cartpage">
                                <td class="text-center"><img src="{{asset('uploads/products/' . $cartlist->product->productimage)}}" width="100px;" height="100px;" alt="Image"></td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->brand->name}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->productname}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->productsize}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">Rp. <span class="price">{{ $cartlist->product->productprice}}</span></td>
                                <td class="cart-product-quantity text-center" width="132px">
                                    <div class="input-group quantity">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend decrement-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1">
                                        <div class="input-group-append increment-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">+</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span class="subtotal" id="subtotal">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="/product-cart/delete/{{$cartlist->id}}" class="d-inline btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="text-left mt-3">
                    <h5 class="bold">Total: <span class="grandtotal" id="grandtotal"></span>
                        <input id="grandtotal" type="hidden" name="grandtotal" value="">
                    </h5>

                    <p>Delivery and discount will be calculated during the checkout process.</p>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartlists}}" name="cartlists">
```

**Controller**
This is where I send the request for grand total `$order->grand_total = $request->grandtotal;`

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
        $cartlists = Cart::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        //get all product from cart
        $products = [];
        foreach ($cartlists as $cartlist) {
            $product = Product::where('id', '=', $cartlist->product_id)->first();
            $products[] = $product;
        }


        $carts = Cart::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        if ($carts->count() > 0) {

            $order = new Order();
            $order->order_number = 'ORD-' . strtoupper(mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999));
            $order->status = 'pending';
            $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $order->grand_total = $request->grandtotal;
            $order->save();

            foreach ($carts as $cart) {
                $order_product = new order_product();
                $order_product->order_id = $order->id;
                $order_product->product_id = $cart->product_id;
                $order_product->is_review = 'no';
                $order_product->save();
            }

            //get all shipment
            $shipments = Shipment::all();

            //get all user address
            $addresses = Address_Delivery_Users::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

            $detailaddresses = null;

            return view('/transactions/delivery', compact('order', 'addresses', 'detailaddresses', 'shipments', 'products'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('status', 'There is no product on your cart, pick some!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass span value into laravel controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719033/how-to-pass-span-value-into-laravel-controller)

Comment: hi, i already saw the solution for that question but it doesnt work on mine (still return null) because in my span tag the value is null not declare like that question.

Comment: How that value gets submitted to server ? Using ajax ?

Comment: im using a http requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you took the wrong selector.

```
var data = $('#grandtotal').html();
```

This gets you the html of the input field, but you want to get the inner html of the span. So you will have to get all elements of class grandtotal and take the first item.

```
var data = $('.grandtotal').first().html();
```

but I would simply add an id like: `grandtotal-span`:

```
<h5 class="bold">Total:
  <span id="grandtotal-span"></span>
  <input id="grandtotal" type="hidden" name="grandtotal" value="">
</h5>
```

and then you are able to get it like you wanted:

```
var data = $('#grandtotal-span').html();
```

Another option would be that you add some listeners and change the values accordingly.

Comment: i already change it but it doesnt seems working. i still return null for that.

Comment: then please show the code that sends the request

Comment: hi, i already edited the code above by adding the controller. please take a look on it. @Aless55

Comment: hmm the code looks fine, if you want you can share the view and the whole JS script, I will take a look at it.

Comment: okay, thankyou very much i already updated the whole view and JS script

Comment: hi @Aless55, i already solved the problem by adding some value inside the ```span``` tag, so it wouldnt null when i pass the value.. i still use your code and adding value into the span. here's what i mean ```<span class="grandtotal">0</span>```so thankyou so much for the help!